# Databind only 3 columns of a table in Gridview

Tags: gridview, datatable, dataset

Hey i have a simple ASP.NET application Table with this schema:
id | Owner | Customer | SentOn | Deleted |. I want the gridview to show only Owner | Customer | SentOn columns of the DataTable which is inside the DataSet. How can i do this?

---

***Note:***
I want to do this programmatic without any dataSource Controls. I want to display CheckBox column for Deleted field, is this possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set AutoGenerateColumns="false".  Add a BoundField for each column that you want to display, and a CheckBoxField for the Deleted column.

Answer (score 0):

Lol :D just use a DataBound field i suppose. Else make visible property of the UnUsed column to False